# Mapping values between arrays with numba.guvectorize

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, numba

I am very new to *numba*. I have an `n`-sized "index" array (`configuration`) containing integers in `[0,m)` and a "mapping" array (`phase_values`) of size `m`. What I want is to map each element of the `configuration` array to the corresponding value from `phase_values` using [numba.guvectorize](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/vectorize.html#the-guvectorize-decorator).

In numpy, the function looks like:

```py
def configuration_to_phase_shifts_numpy(configuration, phase_values):
    map_states_to_phase_shifts = np.vectorize(lambda s: phase_values[s])
    return map_states_to_phase_shifts(configuration)
```

Following numba's documentation, the equivalent vectorized code I understand I need is:

```py
@numba.guvectorize([(numba.int64[:], numba.complex128[:], numba.complex128[:])], '(n),(m)->(n)',nopython=True)
def configuration_to_phase_shifts(configuration, phase_values, phase):
    for i in range(configuration.shape[0]):
        phase[i] = phase_values[configuration[i]]
```

However, when compiling during the first call of the function:

```
phase = configuration_to_phase_shifts(configuration, phase_values)
```

numba throws the following error:

```
Untyped global name 'configuration_to_phase_shifts': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'numpy.ufunc'>
```

So, (apart from the obvious question of how to make it work), I cannot understand why my function is "untyped" - when I have used the `guvectorize` decorator, have declared an output argument and have a symbolic output layout defined?

---

---

### Edit motivated by @aerobiomat 's answer

The above error arises when I am calling the vectorized function within a `@numba.njit` decorated function, e.g.:

```py
@numba.njit
def foo():
    phase_values  = np.array([1,2,3], dtype=complex)
    configuration = np.array([0,0,1,1,2,2])
    phase         = configuration_to_phase_shifts(configuration_to_phase_shifts)
    do_stuff(phase)
```

```
>>>foo()

Untyped global name 'configuration_to_phase_shifts': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'numpy.ufunc'>
File "<ipython-input>", line 5:
def foo():
    <source elided>
    configuration = np.array([0,0,1,1,2,2])
    phase         = configuration_to_phase_shifts(configuration_to_phase_shifts)
    ^
```

**The numpy indexing approach from the answer however solves the problem**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine without any changes using Numba 0.53 and Python 3.8 on this example:

```
>>> configuration = np.array([1,2,0], dtype=int)
>>> phase_values = np.array([4,6,8,1], dtype=complex)
>>> configuration_to_phase_shifts(configuration, phase_values)
array([6.+0.j, 8.+0.j, 4.+0.j])
```

However, the same result can be obtained using pure numpy, which doesn't need any further optimization:

```
>>> phase_values[configuration]
array([6.+0.j, 8.+0.j, 4.+0.j])
```

This should be a comment instead of an answer, but formatting is harder in comments.

Comment: Thank you very much. The pure numpy indexing method solved my problem. FYI, you can check my edit in my question that provides new context for the error - motivated by the fact that your example works for me as well outside of a `@nb.njit` function